# Find string in httpxml.responseText

Tags: ajax

Below is my code which I am trying to find 'Username Ok' in the respone text, and then flag UserNameOk as true. I cannot get this working.

```
function check_username(username)
{
    var httpRequest;
    make_request()
    function stateck() 
    {

        if(httpxml.readyState==4)

         {  
            if (httpxml.responseText == "Username Ok")
            {
                 UserNameOk = true;

            }
             else 
            {
                UserNameOk = false;
            }
        checkCanSubmit();
        document.getElementById("user_div").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
         }
    }

    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
    user_url="ajax_username.php?username=" + username.value;
    httpxml.open("GET",user_url,true);
    httpxml.send(null);

}
```

Below is my checkCanSubmit code

```
function checkCanSubmit()
{
    if (UserNameOk && PasswordOk && EmailOk)
    {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled= false;
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled= true;
    }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: the response might be something like "Username Ok\n" (the '\n' being a newline character which you can't see).  Or it might have whitespace at the beginning or end.  You could print out (alert) the length of the string to test that.

Comment: I have just checked the lenght (httpxml.responseText.length) and it says its 40? I have also just alerted the response and checked its "Username Ok" which it is

Comment: Well 40 is way too long, there must be some characters you aren't seeing.  A quick fix for you might be:

`if (httpxml.responseText.indexOf("Username Ok") >= 0)`

But if you really want to find out what these invisible characters are, you could try: `alert(escape(httpxml.responseText));`

I wonder if it will be something like "<HTML><BODY>Username Ok</BODY></HTML>" (37 chars).  alert() probably hides the tags.  ;)

Comment: Thanks I used (httpxml.responseText.indexOf("Username Ok") >= 0)
Seems to be working :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the correct response come in through firebug?

First step is to make sure your server is returning the correct response by looking at firebug.  I might also simplify the code to help narrow down the issues.  Try:

```
function check_username(username)
{
    var httpRequest;
    make_request()
    function stateck() 
    {

            if(httpxml.readyState==4)

             {  
                    if (httpxml.responseText == "Username Ok")
                    {
                             alert('1');
                             UserNameOk = true;

                    }
                     else 
                    {
                            alert('2');
                            UserNameOk = false;
                    }
             }
    }

    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
    user_url="ajax_username.php?username=" + username.value;
    httpxml.open("GET",user_url,true);
    httpxml.send(null);
```

Can you be more specific about where the problem is?

Comment: Yeh I no the correct response is coming through because I see the response from this line:
    document.getElementById("user_div").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
That works fine. My problem is that the responseText is showing as "Username Ok" but it is not being flagged as true.

Comment: I have just tested the above and I get the alert two. Although I have checked the responseText and it does equal Username Ok

Comment: yea maybe you need to strip the response.  actually throw alert(httpxml.responseText); right before the if statement and see what it prints

Comment: ah nevermind, elliott just did that. Use this function to truncate the response to 11 characters:
function truncate(str, len){
    if(str.length > len){
        return str.substring(0, len).replace(/\s+$/,'') + '...';
    }else{
        return str;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks, How am I using that function? like this?

str = httpxml.responseText;
   len = httpxml.responseText.length;
   truncate(str, len);